# Ext2 utility "e2cp" alternative for OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem

In my linux machines, I use the command line utility e2cp to copy files from and to ext2 disk images. Unfortunately, OS X does not provide any ext2fs utility out of the box.
Is there a version of e2cp that is compatible to OS X, or a similar alternative? Notice that I don't need to mount or do anything advanced, I just have to copy files.

Comment: It sounds like you can use homebrew to install e2fsprogs on OS X. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249071/cant-seem-to-install-e2fsprogs-properly might also help.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you've got two options to mount ext2/3 filesystems in OS X:

1. [fuse-ext2](https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2) plugin for [Fuse for OS X](https://osxfuse.github.io): open-source projects that appear to be fairly active.
2. [ExtFS for Mac OS X by Paragon](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/): Currently $20 with a free 10 day trial; their page is a little confusing referencing "ExtFS for Mac® 9", which appears to be the version 9 iteration of their product, not Mac OS 9.

Comment: I don't actually need to mount filesystems, I need a command line replacement of e2cp to copy files from and to a disk image, because it is part of my automated build process.

Comment: Let's break this down a bit - what format are your disk images? Are they just whole ext2 disks `dd`ed into a single file?