# Can't seem to install e2fsprogs properly

Tags: homebrew, path

I'm following a tutorial requiring me to use mke2fs. I found that I could install it by brew using `brew install e2fsprogs`

Tthis returned the following:

```
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

This brew installs several commands which override OS X-provided file system commands.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/e2fsprogs/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/e2fsprogs/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/e2fsprogs/1.42.13: 135 files, 5.0M
```

So i tried using `brew link e2fsprogs` which then returned `119 symlinks created`

But the command mke2fs is still not available. Anyone who can throw me a bone here?

Comment: How does your PATH look like? And what does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/*e2f*` return?

Comment: since its keg-only you may need to run brew link -force to really create the symlinks (at least this was so on my maschine - with only brew link it complained about not doing it because of keg-only). what od you get when you enter `which mke2fs` in your terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually brew executables (except brew itself) are linked to /usr/local/bin/ which is in the PATH already.

Since *e2fsprogs* executables are also installed to a subsequent sbin folder, force linking them with `brew ln --force e2fsprogs` will create a new folder /usr/local/sbin which contains the links to the sbins.

This new folder is **not** in the PATH. Simply add or extend an already existing  line

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

in ~/.bash_profile.

To update PATH in your current Terminal session immediately, simply enter:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Or close your Terminal window and open a new one.